# Why does gtk_widget_shape_combine_region only work for toplevel windows?

Tags: c, gtk

I am trying to make some parts of the widget (more specific WebKitGTK) invisible both for clicks and on screen. I found the function:

```
void gtk_widget_shape_combine_region (GtkWidget *widget,
                             cairo_region_t *region);
```

> Sets a shape for this widget’s GDK window. This allows for transparent
>   windows etc., see gdk_window_shape_combine_region() for more
>   information.

It is exactly what I want, but it doesn't work for the single widgets, but it works if I call it on the toplevel window. gdk_window_shape_combine_region() in its description says:

> This function works on both toplevel and child windows.

I'm not sure what do they mean by child windows, but I thought it could be widgets, because as I've read GTK doesn't support child windows.

Comment: Does your child widget have a GDK window? (`gtk_widget_set_has_window(w, TRUE)`?) That being said I'm not sure if this is the right method for your needs; I'm pretty sure a lot of GTK+ relies on widgets being rectangular. A more core GTK+ developer would need to confirm.

Comment: On a reference page it said that gtk_widget_set_has_window: "This function should only be called by widget implementations, and they should call it in their init() function." I'm not creating my own widget so I'm not sure if I can call it. But I've tried gtk_widget_get_has_window() and it returns TRUE